# Favicon on AWS S3

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I host my favicon icon and other assets (apple icon, windows tile) on S3/Cloudfront or do they need to be in the root of my website?

If they can be on S3/Cloudfront do I need any different code to implement?

Comment: You have already accepted an answer that will work, but a more complete answer depends on whether your web site itself is hosted behind CloudFront, or you're only using CloudFront for a portion of your assets.   Depending on those factors, it can go either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just store your favicon in your root. Other assets can be stored in S3. As far as needing new code that's up to you. For simplicities sake you can generate a URL to the item in s3 and load them on an HTML page as you normally would.