# How to load a favicon from Amazon AWS CDN?

Tags: html, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, favicon

I have built my web app using AngularJS and it loads various microsites for displaying different content that all have a different fav icon.

I am using a Amazon AWS CDN to host all images, and fav icons since we do not want to store the fav icons in the root directory of the server to save space.

I have the following problem:

- Fav icons for each micro site are not always updated properly. Either an older cached fav icon or is displayed or a fav icon is not displayed at all and we get the following error:

  favicon.ico 404 (not found)
- Our code is the following:

  < link id="dynamic-favicon" rel="icon" href="https://xxxxxx-  prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/imgs/000/000/002/original/favicon.ico?v=2" >

I have added the ?v=2 since I read that this forcefully updates the fav icon on the client side. I have had no luck.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: About the 404 issue, I'd suggest checking the permissions per favicon file and your S3 bucket(s) policy.

Comment: do you have other assets in your s3 bucket that loads properly ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes it does. Aayush on some machines the fav icon loads, on others it does not.

Comment: Use "Cache-control" header and do not cache the favicon and see if the problem persists.

Comment: S3 is not a CDN.  CloudFront is the AWS CDN service.  Are you using CloudFront?  If not, the word "CDN" does not apply here and is confusing the issue, since it implies a caching infrastructure that does not exist.

Comment: @error2007s how do you set this up in angular js/javascript to avoid caching the fav icon?

Comment: See below config var config = {
            headers : {
                "Pragma": "no-cache",
                "Expires": -1,
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            }
        };

Comment: @error2007s will this only not cache fav-icon or stop caching for the whole site? We still want to cache the content of the rest of the site.

Comment: You are storing all the favicon icons on a S3 bucket right?

Comment: @error2007s all favicons are stored inside a S3 bucket

Comment: Well above header option will not work then. In the link described by you in the question you are using the AWS S3 link to the image so that image is not served from the AWS CDN but from the AWS S3 directly and AWS S3 has a Eventual read after write consistency thats why the image is getting error.

Comment: @error2007s is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Change this link xxxxxx- prod.s3.amazonaws.com to your CDN link in above code and see if it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Favicon on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677286/favicon-on-aws-s3)